# Swift ios - fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(texture:color:size)'

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, runtime-error, sprite-kit

I have a Swift file titled Entity.swift:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class Entity: SKSpriteNode { // possibly turn this into a protocol
    init(imageNamed: String) {
        alive = true
        health = 1
        SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        super.init()
    }

    var alive:Bool {
        didSet {
            if !alive {
                self.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }

    var health:Int {
        didSet {
            if health == 0 {
                alive = false
            }
        }
    }

    func modifyHealth(n: Int) {
        health += n
    }

    func getHealth() -> Int {
        return health
    }

    func setHealth(h: Int) {
        health = h
    }

    func isAlive() -> Bool {
        return alive
    }

    func setAlive(a: Bool) {
        alive = a
    }
}
```

This is meant to be a superclass that other classes can implement, e.g. Enemy or Player. I considered making this a protocol since no instance of Entity will ever be made, but I want to be able to have methods in Entity. There is an error at the line `class Entity: SKSpriteNode {`: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

The error also says: `spritekit_game_test/Entity.swift: 13: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(texture:color:size:)' for class 'spritekit_game_test.Entity'`

Any advice on what these errors mean and how to fix them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I paste your code into a project, it doesn't compile, telling me: "Class 'Entity' does not implement its superclass's required members". Are you using beta 5?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending texture/color/size attributes to the init for the Entity, when the Entity class only accepts imageNamed: String

Please post/recheck your code that calls/creates your Entity class